# ErrorException: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, bool given in file

Tags: laravel, eloquent

got this error while running this code

```
foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem) {
        if (in_array($orderItem['product_id'], $coupon->products_applicable)) {
            $coupon->products_applicable = true;
       }  
     }
```

the dd of product_applicable is

```
 dd($coupon->products_applicable)

    array:2 [
  0 => "2"
  1 => "1"
]
```

The dd of $orderItems is

```
    Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1553
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => App\OrderItem {#1554
      +hidden: array:3 [
        0 => "created_at"
        1 => "updated_at"
        2 => "deleted_at"
      ]
      +guarded: []
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "order_items"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      -----etc
        
    }
  ]
}
```

**I want to check the product_ids of order items with Products_applicable values**
**note** ->Products_applicable is stored as json in mysql using casts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at ur code

```
foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem) {
   if (in_array($orderItem->product_id, $coupon->products_applicable)) {
      $coupon->products_applicable = true;
   }  
}
```

the first time it works well and then changes array `$coupon->products_applicable` to `true`, so on the second iteration, you have bool value instead of an array.
Do not know your task, but you need to add `break` after this or change code regarding ur task

Answer (score 0):

the error because you assign true to this attribute $coupon->products_applicable after the first time that enter the if block .

```
foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem) {
        if (in_array($orderItem['product_id'], $coupon->products_applicable)) {
            $coupon->products_applicable = true; // this is the error
       }  
 }
```

you can solve this by assign $coupon->products_applicable  to any temp variable like this

```
$temp = $coupon->products_applicable
foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem) {
        if (in_array($orderItem['product_id'], $temp)) {
            $coupon->products_applicable = true; // this is the error
       }  
 }
```